# NoMethodError in SessionsController#create (undefined method `current_user) Hartl Chapter 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When i sign into the sample app i've made from Hartl's rail tutorial at the end of Chapter 9 i get this error. I've searched high and low but can't figure out what's probably very obvious.

> NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
>
> undefined method `current_user=' for #session....

The errors occur in these 2 files, code below

> app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:7:in `sign_in'
>   app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:9:in`create'

**app/helpers/sessions_helper**

```
  module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user
    remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
  end

  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url if request.get?
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/sessions_controller**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at listing 8.20 on http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out.  It looks like you missed the step of defining the `current_user=` method

```
  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look but I don't think that's it. Listing 9.16 changes "@current_user = user" to "user == current_user"

Comment: @Abraham - Peter is correct. In the `sign_in` method in your sessions helper you are calling `self.current_user=` yet that method does not exist. Listing 9.16 refers to the `current_user?` method.

Comment: @Peter - you were right, my mistake. As a noob i didn't correctly understand what you meant. I completely missed it out! Thanks veritas1 for helping me see it.